# Uncaught ReferenceError: buyNft is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Am I missing to add some script or what? I am getting error from title. How can I solve this, if you can help me, I would be grateful. I tried adding different scripts, but I amgetting the same error.

```
 <a onclick="buyNft({{$nft->id}})">{{trans('nft.buy')}}</a>
    
        @push('scripts')
            <script>
        
                function buyNft(nftid) {
                    swal({
                        title: "Are You Sure?",
                        text: "Do you want to buy this nft?",
                        type: 'warning',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        
        
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result) {
                            axios.post("/buythisnft/" + nftid).then(response => {
                                window.location.reload();
                            });
        
                        }
                    });
        
                }
            </script>
        @endpush
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buyNft-function needs to be declared BEFORE you echo out any element with "onclick=buyNft()":

```html
@push('scripts')
  <script>
      function buyNft(nftid) {
          // ...
      }
  </script>
@endpush
 
 <a onclick="buyNft({{$nft->id}})">{{trans('nft.buy')}}</a>
```

UPDATE: This is an example using a script at the bottom of the page which creates an eventlistener for click-events:

```js
document.addEventListener("click",e => {
  if(e.target.closest(".buyNft")){
    e.preventDefault();

    alert("You want to buy an NFT.")
    
    //... Replace with your own functions ...
  }
})
```

```html
<a class="buyNft" href="#">Buy that NFT</a>
<br /><br />
<a href="#">Some other link on this page</a>
```

Comment: It works like that, but is it possible to add at the bottom. Now I am getting warning in Console: error compiling template:

Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.

Comment: Why not put the JS in a separate file and load it in the head?

Comment: If you want to add the script to the bottom of the page, you need to work with event listeners.
You can give your triggers classes like "nftBuyButton" and create eventlisteners for click-events on these.

Comment: I just added a small example of how to do it using a click-event-listener and event-delegation. Using event delegation it is no longer important, where you place the script, be it the header or the footer of your website.